# onclick button save data .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button, razor, onclick

I have a asp.net mvc razor file. The button needs to send data to the database. This is the code I have. The database is connected and working on a server. I just can't get the button to send the data to the database. An onclick event with javascript I have tried but nothing seems to work. Could someone explain what I should do? It's my first time working with .cshtml and I don't really know how to solve this problem.

PROBLEM IS SOLVED.
I was using the wrong names.. I referred in the C# part of the .cshtml to the id of the input and not the name..

```
@{
Validation.RequireField("achternaam", "Achternaam is verplicht.");
Validation.RequireField("voornaam", "Voornaam is verplicht.");
Validation.RequireField("organisatie", "Organisatie is verplicht.");
Validation.RequireField("email", "Email is verplicht.");
Validation.RequireField("datum", "Datum is verplicht.");
Validation.RequireField("tijd", "Tijd is verplicht.");

var achternaam = "";
var voornaam = "";
var organisatie = "";
var email = "";
var datum = "";
var tijd = "";

if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid())
{
    achternaam = Request.Form["achternaam"];
    voornaam = Request.Form["voornaam"];
    organisatie = Request.Form["organisatie"];
    email = Request.Form["email"];
    datum = Request.Form["datum"];
    tijd = Request.Form["tijd"];


    using (var db = new Blub._1.Database.blubEntities())
    {
        // Insert
        var bezoeker = new Blub._1.Database.visitor
        {
            AchterNaam = achternaam,
            VoorNaam = voornaam,
            Bedrijf = organisatie,
            DatumBezoek = Convert.ToDateTime(datum),
            Email = email
        };                   

    Response.Redirect("~Bezoeker");
}
```

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Als voorbeeld ...</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <br />
    <a href="/OverzichtWerknemer">Overzicht</a>
    <br />
    <a href="/Bezoeker">Nieuwe bezoeker</a>
    <br />
    <a href="/Contractor">Nieuwe contractor</a>
</div>

<div id="section">
    <form name="login" action="~/OverzichtWerknemer.cshtml" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Achternaam*:</b></td>
                <td>
                    <input id="achternaam" name="LastName" type="text" maxlength="60" style="width:146px; border:1px solid #999999" required />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Voornaam*:</b></td>
                <td>
                    <input id="voornaam" name="FirstName" type="text" maxlength="60" style="width:146px; border:1px solid #999999" required/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Organisatie*:</b></td>
                <td><input id="organisatie" name="Organization" type="text" maxlength="60" style="width:300px; border:1px solid #999999" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Emailadres*:</b></td>
                <td><input id="email" name="FromEmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="60" style="width:300px; border:1px solid #999999" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Dag van bezoek*:</b></td>
                <td><input id="datum" name="FromDate" type="date" style="width:300px; border:1px solid #999999" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Tijdstip*</b></td>
                <td><input id="tijd" name="TimeVisit" type="time" maxlength="60" style="width:300px; border:1px solid #999999" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    * - Verplicht veld. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" value="Registreer" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Copyright
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the method name ?

Comment: A method name isn't needed in this .cshtml file

Answer (score 2):

I think you must have a form tag with an action like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/ControllerName/ActionName">
```

Or use helpers as #Kypaz suggests :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", null (adapt to route), FormMethod.Post))
{

 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the url helper

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" >
```